# Log4j properties for an Webservice/API

Tags: log4j

In my project there are multiple Rest webservices/APIs where I need to have a separate log file for each webservice with appropriate Input request, processing steps and response. All these webservice will call the same jar.

I have tried the below configurations but the common jar processing logs are getting logged in all the api logs.The root package of the common jar is  fr.com.api.common . I have even placed the addivity as false,but it is not working.

```
log4j.appender.api1Log=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.api1Log.File=api1Log.log
log4j.appender.api1Log.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.api1Log.Append=true
log4j.appender.api1Log.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.api1Log.MaxFileSize=50000KB
log4j.appender.api1Log.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.api1Log.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.api1Log.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n

log4j.logger.fr.com.api.rest.api1=INFO, api1Log
log4j.additivity.fr.com.api.rest.api1=false


log4j.appender.api2Log=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.api2Log.File=api2Log.log
log4j.appender.api2Log.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.api2Log.Append=true
log4j.appender.api2Log.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.api2Log.MaxFileSize=50000KB
log4j.appender.api2Log.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.api2Log.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.api2Log.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n

log4j.logger.fr.com.api.rest.api2=INFO, api2Log
log4j.additivity.fr.com.api.rest.api2=false

log4j.logger.fr.com.api.common=INFO,api2Log,api1Log
log4j.additivity.fr.com.api.common=false
```